# Exclude category from single product description( woocommerce) and make it not linkable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress theme with woocommerce. Every single product have in description category like categories : new, books.  I want to exclude one category(new) and make it not clickable(remove a hrev)   I found line of this tag but dont know how to edit right. Any ideas? THANKS!

```
<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>
```

[woocommerce plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this line:

```
<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>
```

with this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
echo '<span class="posted_in">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
        if( $term->name == 'New' ){
            echo ' ' . $term->name;
        }else{
            echo ' <a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        }
    }
echo '</span>';
```

You can customize it according to your requirements. May be this will help.

Comment: it works ! but there is some moments i want to solve if it is possible. I will be happy to remove category 'new' from this listing  and add simple text like (PRODUCT TYPE :)  , THANKS

Comment: if( $term->name == 'New' ){
// do nothing
}else{ 

this is right code to remove cat,  woocoomerce authors gave to me. THANKS HAIDER!!

Comment: You welcome brother and thanks to Stackoverflow community. :)